# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API swagger spec

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, openapi-generator

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API written using C# where the `Produces` attribute is set to `application/json` and we are using the OpenAPI generator to generate the API client.

But we get an error:

> openapi_client.exceptions.ApiValueError: Invalid content_type returned. Content_type='application/json; charset=utf-8' was returned when only {'application/json'} are defined for status_code=400

The initial fix seemed to be to add

```
Produces("application/json; charset=utf-8")
```

but then the server started returning 406 and from looking at other posts, this doesn't seem to be correct.

Is there a way to get the `swagger.json` to generate the content type like this:

```
"content": {
    "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
```

so that the generated client will work correctly? Or is is possibly an issue with the OpenAPI generator?

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Core, when you use the `[Produces]` attribute to specify the response content type, you should only specify the media type (e.g., `application/json`) without specifying the character set (e.g., `charset=utf-8`) like below:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
```